# How to make Ruby JSON parser ignore json_class?

Tags: ruby, json, chef-infra

I have a serialized JSON String (chef role definition actually) and it has a json_class key, making the ruby JSON parser try to force it to be a Chef::Role object. How can I make the parser ignore this key and just simply deserialize into a normal Hash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and found the answer by reading the source of the JSON gem - just  unset JSON.create_id before trying to do the parse:

```
JSON.create_id = nil
JSON.parse('{ "json_class": "Chef::Role" }').class => Hash
```

**EDIT:** Note that since version 1.7 of the gem (1.8.0 is current as I type this update), the above hack is no longer necessary.  `JSON#parse` now ignores `json_class`, and `JSON#load` should be used instead for unmarshalling dumped objects.

Comment: Wow, that looks like a hack, but it really is the documented API: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#create_id

Answer (score 6):

The "json_class" key is there to indicate what Object the json should be un-marshaled as.  It is added by JSON.dump.  In more recent versions of JSON, `JSON.parse` will ignore "json_class", un-marshaling to a Hash.  While `JSON.load` will un-marshal to the indicated Object (in your case, a Chef::Role).

```
JSON.parse('{ "json_class": "Chef::Role" }').class => Hash
JSON.load('{ "json_class": "Chef::Role" }').class => Chef::Role
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, Matt. I've edited my answer to reflect that for future passersby.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do a `gsub` on the string before parsing, and change that particular key to something else.

How about showing a sample of the JSON before and after?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, Mark Reed's solution should certainly work.  But when I tried this in a Vagrantfile:

```
JSON.create_id = nil
vagrant_json = JSON.parse(Pathname(__FILE__).dirname.join('nodes', "#{node_name}.json").read)

config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]
  chef.roles_path = "roles"
  chef.data_bags_path = "data_bags"
  chef.node_name = node_name
  chef.run_list = vagrant_json.delete('run_list')
  chef.json = vagrant_json
end
```

the vagrant_json.class was a Hash, but it still retained the json_class value internally whenever the node.json file contained the **"json_class": "Chef::Node"** entry.  Then when using the hash to set the chef.json value in the last line, it was again interpreted using the json class (and the result was, oddly, an empty run list.)

Here's what worked.  Same idea, but a bit less finesse:

```
vagrant_json = JSON.parse(Pathname(__FILE__).dirname.join('nodes', "#{node_name}.json").read)
vagrant_json['json_class'] = nil  # <== This worked

config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]
  chef.roles_path = "roles"
  chef.data_bags_path = "data_bags"
  chef.node_name = node_name
  chef.run_list = vagrant_json.delete('run_list')
  chef.json = vagrant_json
end
```

This code worked to set both the json attributes and the run list from a Chef node file, with or without the **"json_class": "Chef::Node"** entry.

In summary, the previous answer does seem completely correct in relation to getting a hash from JSON.parse, but if you don't remove the json_class pair from that hash, there can still be trouble later, as in this case.